# Remove duplicate library Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have multiple libraries in Android Studio. Two of them are Pushbots and Universal Image Loader. After updating the Pushbots library to the latest version it seems that Pushbots also contain Universal Image Loader inside it. So now there are two Universal Image Loader and the classes seems to have been duplicated and is causing a no suitable method found error.

How can I make Android Studio just use one library for my app module and for the other library? Is that possible or there is an official workaround?

Comment: Show `build.gradle`. You maybe to exclude one of the dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed in 2.0.9 release, check change log

> v2.0.9 — March 01, 2015  Bug fixes:
>   - Fix conflict with Universal Image Uploader dependency.
>   - Fix custom push handler bugs.

http://pushbots.com/developer/download/android

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove "Universal Image Loader", there is no way around it. I had the same problem with "AirPush" & "BugSense". You have to request for a separate Build without "UIL".

Comment: What if the duplicated library are in different versions and the one I want to keep does not contain the method that I need anymore?

Comment: You have to request for new build from "PutShots"

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Pushbots 2.0.8 SDK had Universal Image Loader with it so it was conflicting with my Universal Image Loader library that I manually added as a jar.

As [Jack Dre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2830635/jack-dre) mentioned, this was fixed in Pushbots 2.0.9. I however was able to fix it by deleting my Universal Image Loader and used the Universal Image Loader and using the one that was included in Pushbots instead. All I did was to update the imports on my classes to the correct namespace.